# Weird behavior of `map()`

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome

*A.S.: Variable names were changed for simplicity.*

My goal is to create new array-like class, every instance of which will have seven numbers, based on whatever quantity of whatever arguments.

So, the code is something like this:

```
"use strict";
class SevenNumbers extends Array {
    constructor(...args) { debugger; // !
        // Cut the rest; fill the gaps; convert: first to object, then to primitive
        super(...Object.assign([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], args.slice(0, 7)).map(arg => +new Number(arg)));
    }
}
```

It works fine, so `new SevenNumbers();` returns array of seven numbers, either default (0), or not.
The `debugger`-part is important: it tells us about getting into constructor of a `SevenNumbers` class.

The problem emerges when I try to `map()` gotten object.
Try the following code:

```
var arr = new SevenNumbers(8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1);
// SevenNumbers [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2] (without the last).
arr.map(_ => _);
// Array [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2].
```

First part works in predicted way, but at the 3rd line we're getting in the constructor again!
The most confusing thing is that the only argument here is the length of `arr`. Why the length?

Although the final result is correct, this weird behavior interferes with my work in practice, since there are additional calculations in between.

What is wrong here? Why doesn't it just take values from ready custom array, why create new one?

Comment: Maybe the `.map` function instead of just creating an Array creates an instance of its caller? (Especially if this caller extends from an array).

Comment: @coyotte508: Then  why does it take the `length` property as an argument? This part of issue is the weirdest.

Comment: In Chrome (or Firefox) the debugger doesn't stop in the constructor on the `.map` call, maybe you should specify the browser used.

Comment: @coyotte508: It's Chrome. I use `52.0.2743.24 beta` now, but the problem appears in older versions of stable Chrome too.

Comment: @DmitryParzhitsky: Because `new Array(length)` is the standard constructor.

Comment: Actually the result of the `map` invocation should be a `SevenNumbers […]` not an `Array […]` (if the engine followed the ES6 spec)?!

Comment: @coyotte508: https://jsfiddle.net/gnhjqkrx/

Comment: On Chrome (50.0.2661.102, Win 10) and FF I get only #1, but on Edge I get both (#1 and #2).

Comment: @Bergi: It is not expected: [`Array.prototype.map` calls `callbackfn` once for each element in the array, in ascending order, and constructs a new Array from the results](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.map).

Comment: Actually it is expected. "The abstract operation ArraySpeciesCreate with arguments originalArray and length is used to specify the creation of a new Array object using a **constructor function** that is derived from **originalArray**. It performs the following steps:"

Comment: Why `+new Number(arg)`? How is this better than `+arg`?

Comment: @RobG: This is simplification. I use another custom function at this place, which returns number.

Comment: @DmitryParzhitsky—Ok, just wondering if there was some nuance of `+new Number(5)` that I'd missed. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `map` uses [ArraySpeciesCreate](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrayspeciescreate) to create an array like the original one.

If this didn't happen, at the end you would get a normal `Array` instead of a `SevenNumbers` instance.

Therefore, your constructor is called in order to construct the new array which will be filled using the callback function and the items of the original instance.

If you don't want it, you can use `Symbol.species` to make `map` call `Array` instead of `SevenNumbers`.

```js
class SevenNumbers extends Array {
  constructor(...args) { 
    console.log(args.toString());
    super(...Object.assign([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], args.slice(0, 7)).map(arg => +new Number(arg)));
  }
  static get [Symbol.species]() { return Array; }
}
new SevenNumbers(8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1).map(_ => _);
```

Comment: Worth adding to this that `Symbol.species`, where supported, can be used to alter this behavior.

Comment: @Retsam Yes, I was going to mention it but couldn't make it work at first. I thought it was stored at some step as an own data property, but it's a getter inherited from `Array`.